# iOS - plist whitelisting for Jailbroken device

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic app for iOS [phone/ipad] and want to avoid user launching app. on jailbroken devices.
To achieve this, am using the below plugin.

https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-jailbreak-detection

In iOS 9
Initial error:

**The app. is not allowed to query for scheme cydia ...**

After adding in plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>cydia</string>
</array>
```

Error:
**-canOpenURL: failed for URL:
 "****" - error: "(null)"**

Is there any alternative which I can customise in code for iOS 9?

Help is appreciated !

Comment: FYI: Detecting jail breaking will not stop people from altering your app to remove such detection. You are fighting a losing battle.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I am not bothered about later part .. We can detect if device is jailbroken .. I am looking for this feature to be enabled .. But this is an issue only in iOS 9 ..

Comment: @Gene It could be the lack of [mcve], or someone thought the question not-useful, the unclear intent behind the question, or [someone lost their keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).